# resolve IP address(int) to name

Tags: c#, string, dns, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get domain name from Given IP in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252845/how-to-get-domain-name-from-given-ip-in-c)

How can i convert ip address in int format to string format.
for example, i have this ip address in int format, `173.194.38.138` and i want to convert to string `www.rugadingku.blogspot.com`. I saw a lots of example on how to convert ip string to int, but not int to string.

Comment: well, you need to build up a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table)

Comment: You know that one IP can be shared among many, many hosts, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252845/how-to-get-domain-name-from-given-ip-in-c

Comment: Note: No solution listed here is guaranteed to work. Doing this relies on reverse-DNS, which a particular IP address may or may not have setup. Also, you may get an unexpected hostname because an IP can be tied to multiple DNS names/domains

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code to convert IP Address to HostName :

```
IPHostEntry IpToDomainName = Dns.GetHostEntry("173.194.38.138");
string hostname =IpToDomainName.HostName;
```

[Dns.GetHostByAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry.aspx)

also you can use this way :

```
 System.Net.IPHostEntry ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress("173.194.38.138");
 string hostname = ip.HostName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:not tested

visit http://www.dijksterhuis.org/converting-an-ip-address-to-a-hostname-and-back-with-c/

```
// Map an IP address to a hostname

IPHostEntry IpToDomainName = Dns.GetHostEntry("209.85.173.99");
Console.WriteLine("DomainName: {0}", IpToDomainName.HostName);
```

Also try this:

```
public static string getDNSName(string myIP)
{
 System.Net.IPHostEntry ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(myIP);
 return ip.HostName;
}
```