# Get Domain from IP

Tags: c#, dns, hostname

I am just playing around with some web crawling, and I just have a question regarding getting host names, I am coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252845/how-to-get-domain-name-from-given-ip-in-c) question regarding getting host names. 
 I'll use an example to ask my question, 
e.g. Lets use google.com IP: 74.125.237.19
By using that method i.e.

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(IpAddress.Parse("74.125.237.19")).HostName
```

I get: syd01s04-in-f19.1e100.net
My question how do I get google.com instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to command prompt and type `nslookup 74.125.237.19` :

```
C:\Users\adamp>nslookup 74.125.237.19
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.200.180

Name:    syd01s04-in-f19.1e100.net
Address:  74.125.237.19
```

The reverse DNS for that IP is `syd01s04-in-f19.1e100.net`.  There will be no way for you to get Google.com unless Google changes their reverse DNS for that IP.

Read this for more info on the 1e100.net domain: [What is 1e100.net](http://support.google.com/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174717)