# Get Destination URL from Another Application to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, url, wireshark, sniffing

I wondered how to get URL destination like `Sniffer/Wireshark/Proxifier` does on VB.net

so, the application detects all destination URL from all applications running on Windows, and output it into listbox on VB.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties` object to retrieve all existing connections:

```
Private Sub list_active_connections()
    Dim _IPGlobalProperties As System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
    For Each conn As System.Net.NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation In _IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections
        ListBox1.Items.Add(conn.RemoteEndPoint.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solve :D . but how to get the domain than the IP Destination if available :D

Comment: @faisalakbar You could try with `Dns.GetHostEntry` (see  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252845/how-to-get-domain-name-from-given-ip-in-c)  answer)