# List of IP addresses map it with names

Tags: c#, class, ping

Below is a part of my program. I have some IPs which I ping them but when I print out a success or not message for each one I would like to get a name except from IP. One way is if (192.168.100) then "example" but is there easier way to do this and more dynamically in order to be easier to add addresses?

```
public static string[] addresses = { "192.168.1.100", "192.168.1.254", "192.168.1.253" };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Task<PingReply>> pingTasks = new List<Task<PingReply>>();
    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        pingTasks.Add(PingAsync(address));
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I would like to get a name". Are you asking how o talk to a name sever? Or how to keep a static dictionary in your code?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252845/how-to-get-domain-name-from-given-ip-in-c

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get a name"? You want to name your ips?

Comment: I interpret this question to mean he wants the DNS name belonging to the IP.

Comment: The results of the Ping ends up in the ARP table.  You can see the ARP table from cmd.exe using >ARP -A.  You can query ARP Table in C#.  It is easy than processing the Async results from the ping.

Comment: foe example i have an ip 192.168.1.100 i want to assign this ip to  a name like londonpc this is not a computer name is just a name

Comment: 192.168.1.100    name1
192.168.1.102   name2 to explain i would like to something sql select 192.168.1.100 as name1

Comment: public static string[] addresses = { "192.168.1.100"as name1, "192.168.1.254"as name2, "192.168.1.253"as name3 }; something like that but with right syntax

Comment: like a label name

Comment: Use a [**`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).